# Change user and group of files

Tags: linux, file, unix, file-permissions

I want to know is it possible to change the files user and group to same as user and group of the parent automatically.

    For eg. Existing issue

```
getfacl /home/Test/UPS/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: home/Test/UPS
# owner: user1
# group: basegroup
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

ls -l /home/Test/UPS/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 basegroup 1450 Jul 12 11:54 file.edi

ls -l /home/Test/UPS/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user2 group2 1450 Jul 12 11:54 file.edi

my group2 is part of basegroup

I want files with permission as below automatically whenever file comes into  /home/Test/UPS/ directory.

ls -l /home/Test/UPS/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 basegroup 1450 Jul 12 11:54 file.edi

Please help...
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use force group and force user for samba mounted directories, but am not aware of any way of automatically overriding user and group in local directories